# How to see changes when adding Custom Class to UILabel, in storyboard itself?

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a custom class to UILabel. 
Custom Class is:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomLabel: UILabel {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.setup()

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    self.textColor = UIColor.blue
}
}
```

But I cant see the changes in storyboard. How can it is able to see the changes in the interface builder??

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `IBInspectable` properties to see changes in storyboard

here is  example

```
@IBDesignable class RoundedTextField: UITextField {


    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 0 // You will see this in storyboard 
    @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor = .green  // You will see this in storyboard 

    override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib()
          self.borderStyle = .none
          self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
          self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
          self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
          self.layer.masksToBounds = true
      }
}
```

Don't forgot to set class

[image]

Here how you can see in stoyrboard

[image]

Comment: I want  to see the change in UILabel when I set the class for UILabel,

Comment: @KayCee  Are you able to see the properties in storyboard ?

Comment: i can ( when added IBinspectable) , but this is to change font of all Custom class selected labels.

Comment: @KayCee  If you have used this property  in your code then don't worry you will see in output in simulator or device. as xcode is in not very good in IBInspectable so it not render sometimes in  stroyrboard

Comment: Oh, And when adding IBInspectable, some times all views in View Controller becomes invisible @Prashant

Comment: @KayCee See edit  how I use property in awake from nib

Comment: @KayCee We can't do much on this this is all we need accept until apple fixes this :(

Comment: @KayCee  If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @KayCee Okay No problem :)